# Where the sentence begins, “The portion of the Deposit, if any,” does “if any” apply to portion or Deposit? Emphasis in original

Tags: word-order

Where the sentence follows an election to chose between the deposit or another mutually independent remedy, does the  wording “if any” in “The portion of the Deposit, if any, . . .” apply to portion or Deposit? (Emphasis in original.)

Comment: Please provide more context!!

Comment: During the market collapse I was forced to walk away from a house I could have afforded when we sighed the contract at the beginning of March. I signed a release in arrc

Comment: We need to see the rest of the sentence containing "The portion of the Deposit, if any, . . .”  And perhaps a sentence or two leading up to that.  As it is, we have no idea what "portion" refers to.

Comment: If “if any “ in normal grammar applies to “portion” one party can make a side contract with another party to provide them 100% of the proceeds despite what the contract in dispute  says without notification or asking for a modification. If “if any “ applies to deposit the opposite applies and failure to make the side contract known and ask for a modification constitutes a failure to negotiate in good faith. It would seem to me that the qualifier applies to the closer noun, But?

Comment: Seller may elect to recover and retain the deposit for the account of seller as agreed upon liquidated damages, consideration for exact execution of this contract, and in full settlement of any claims, wereupon buyer and seller shall be relieved from all further obligations under this contract or seller, at shelters option. may [choose a mutually exclusive action in equity not retaining the deposit]. The portion of the deposit, if any, paid to listing Broker upon default of buyer, Shall we split equally . . .”

Comment: Edit your question!!

Comment: It can't just apply to *the portion*, because then the question would be, "The portion of what?" It applies to the entire noun phrase: *the portion of the deposit*.